# How to fix - createdAt.getMinutes - Missing Zero

Tags: html, vue.js, time, datecreated

I encountered an unexpected issue with "${calculate.createdAt.getMinutes()}" It does not show the 0... It should be "13:06" but it shows only 13:6 . How to fix the missing 0? Thanks for advice.

Comment: `getMinutes` returns a number, and when you use a number in a template string, it's not padded. If you want it to be padded, you have to do it yourself, for example with [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) like this

```js
let date = new Date(2021,6,10,10,3,20)
console.log(date);
let minuteString = `${date.getMinutes()}`.padStart(2, "0")
console.log(minuteString);
```

Comment: Nope... shows parsing error due to the back ticks.

Comment: I don't know, what you did with that piece of code, but using backticks is the way to go for string tempates ...

Comment: @Stanislav Perhaps your browser or build setup doesn't support template strings. Alternatively, you could convert the number to string beforehand: `date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')`